# How can I bind a property to another property in Kivy?

Tags: python, properties, kivy

I want to bind a property of a widget to a property of a child widget. Thus when the root widget property is changed, the change is propagated to the child property as well.

I tried it this way:

```
self._Child._MyProperty = self._MyProperty
```

This works... sometimes. But sometimes it does not work. I cannot find out when it works or why and under which conditions it does not work.

In all cases I have a binding to a method in the root widget as well:

```
self.bind(_MyPropert = self._MyPropertyChange)
```

This method is called in all cases, but sometimes the change is not propagated to the child property.

This does not work even if it feels very natural:

```
self.bind(_MyProperty = self._Child._MyProperty)
```

But in Kivy, I could do:

```
<RootWidget>
    <ChildWidget>
        _MyProperty: self.parent._MyProperty
```

The problem is I want to do it in Python, not in Kivy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To bind one property to another you should use the [setter](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.setter) event:

```
self.bind(_MyProperty=self._Child.setter('_MyProperty'))
```

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason. [This](https://pastebin.com/Ppfervuh) is my code so far. But I don't understand what I'm doing wrong in `makeLabel()`.

Comment: @FergusWyrm It works, it just doesn't do anything because you doesn't change value of property you bind to. Change your function [as shown here](https://pastebin.com/xrNBAqcT). You'll see how "Lorem ipsum" appeared.

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what it is. I'll have to figure out if there's a way to manually trigger a property event without actually changing the value.

Comment: @FergusWyrm just to be clear: `self.property('c_description').dispatch(self)` - is a way to trigger a property event without changing the value.